# Discord C# Bot - Delete the latest message

Tags: c#, discord

I am using the rogue exception package for my discord bot.

When a user calls the bot by a command, I want the bot delete his message before executing the command.

So in my "MessageReceived"-Event i have this code so far:

```
private async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage s)
        {
            var msg = s as SocketUserMessage; // the input

            if (msg == null || !msg.Content.StartsWith("!") || msg.Author.IsBot) // return if null, msg is no command, msg is written by the bot
                return;

            if (msg.Channel is SocketGuildChannel guildChannel) // just delete the command if the msg is written in the guild channel, not a private message channel
                await ??? // Delete the command
}
```

So does someone know, what to write there =?

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are using Discord.NET API for your bot.
So from this documentation [here](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketMessage.html).

Take a look at the `Method` list in the properties of `SocketMessage`. (By the way, take a look at the right side of the webpage, you should be able to see a bar that allows you to navigate easily)

> In case you are wondering why we are looking at `SocketMessage`, that is because your delegate will run whenever a user posts a message, and that message is your `SocketMessage`, hence that is what you would want to delete.

You should be able to see a method called: `DeleteAsync`. That would be what you want.
(Screenshot is below)

For the arguments, you can see that its a `RequestOption` datatype and by default it has been set `null` for you. You can change that, but I highly recommend using the default.

> Also a good thing to take note that is the bot will do nothing (and return an exception) if it does not have the permission to manage messages.

[image: Screenshot of the method]

Answer (score 1):

#### Example:

*(sorry, but some of the code strings are in Portuguese... this is a voting system)*

```cs
        [Command("Votar")]
        [Summary("Abro uma votação, com opções de Sim e Não.")]
        [RequireBotPermission(ChannelPermission.AddReactions)]
        public async Task NovoVoto([Remainder] string secondPart)
        {
            Log.CMDLog(Context.User.Username, "Votar", Context.Guild.Name);

            if (secondPart.Length >= 200)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Perdão, porém seu voto não deve ter mais de 200 caracteres");
                return;
            }

            var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.WithColor(new Color(126, 211, 33));
            embed.WithTitle("VOTE AQUI!");
            embed.WithDescription(secondPart);
            embed.WithFooter($"Votação criada por: {Context.User.Username}");

            RestUserMessage msg = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", embed: embed);
            await msg.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("✅"));
            await msg.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("❌"));

            //Delete the command message from the user
            await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
        }
```